# mosquitto_pub succeeds but ThingsBoard device telemetry not updated

Tags: mqtt, mosquitto

I'm using ThingsBoard demo, with a throw-away test device:

- Name: Test
- Device ID: 779e65d0-366f-11e9-b411-fdd6fdf5c064
- Access Token: DdqzgX0Q4QLBbveiuY8e

I set up a subscriber:

```
mosquitto_sub -h demo.thingsboard.io -u DdqzgX0Q4QLBbveiuY8e -t hello
```

Then I publish:

```
mosquitto_pub -h demo.thingsboard.io -u DdqzgX0Q4QLBbveiuY8e -t hello -m hi
```

`mosquitto_pub` returns `0` (success), but I see nothing shown by either `mosquitto_sub` or in the `Test` device's "Latest Telemetry".

How do I get both ThingsBoard and the subscriber to see my `hi` message?

Comment: Every platform has it's own rules as to what it handles.
We followed their https://thingsboard.io/docs/getting-started-guides/helloworld/
and got it to work.

Comment: I have the same beahavior by using the correct form:
mosquitto_pub -h thinksboard_host -t v1/devices/me/telemetry -m '{"answer": 42}' -u device_access_token what could it be?

Answer (score 1):

### TL;DR:

ThingsBoard expects a fixed topic of `v1/devices/me/telemetry` and a JSON message, eg:

```
mosquitto_pub -h demo.thingsboard.io -t v1/devices/me/telemetry -m '{"answer": 42}' -u DdqzgX0Q4QLBbveiuY8e
```

---

The [ThingsBoard MQTT Device API Reference](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/mqtt-api/#telemetry-upload-api) says:

> In order to publish telemetry data to ThingsBoard server node, send PUBLISH message to the following topic:
>
> ```
> v1/devices/me/telemetry
> ```
>
> The simplest supported data formats are:
>
> ```
> {"key1":"value1", "key2":"value2"}
> ```